# Joining results from different tables in a single result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, union

I have the three 'querys' below , which return me 3 tables of different results , I want to unite them into one 'querys' and get a resulting table ordered by the 'DATA_INICIO e HR_INICIO'

```
Select T0.COD_OS_COMPLETO 'OS', t0.COD_BARR 'PP', t0.COD_TP_MAQUINA 'TIPO_SERVICO', T0.COD_FUNCIONARIO 'FUNCIONARIO', T0.DATA 'DATA_INICIO', T0.DATA_FIM 'DATA_FIM', T0.INICIO 'HR_INICIO', T0.FIM 'HR_FIM', T0.TOTAL_HS 'TOTAL_HRS' from dbo.TAPONTA_ABERTO T0
select T0.OS 'OS', t0.COD_PROCESSO 'PP', t0.COD_TP_SERVICO 'TIPO_SERVICO', T0.COD_FUNCIONARIO 'FUNCIONARIO', T0.DATA 'DATA_INICIO', T0.DATA_FIM 'DATA_FIM', T0.INICIO 'HR_INICIO', T0.FIM 'HR_FIM', T0.TOTAL 'TOTAL_HRS' from dbo.TAPS_AUX T0
select T0.COD_OS_COMPLETO 'OS', t0.COD_BARR 'PP', t0.COD_TP_MAQUINA 'TIPO_SERVICO', T0.COD_FUNCIONARIO 'FUNCIONARIO', T0.DATA 'DATA_INICIO', T0.DATA_FIM 'DATA_FIM', T0.INICIO 'HR_INICIO', T0.FIM 'HR_FIM', T0.TOTAL_HS 'TOTAL_HRS' from dbo.TCTRL_PH T0
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined the three tables with `UNION` and`ORDER BY` the `HR_INICIO`

```
SELECT TEMP.* FROM (
    SELECT T0.COD_OS_COMPLETO 'OS', T0.COD_BARR 'PP', T0.COD_TP_MAQUINA 'TIPO_SERVICO', T0.COD_FUNCIONARIO 'FUNCIONARIO', T0.DATA 'DATA_INICIO', T0.DATA_FIM 'DATA_FIM', T0.INICIO 'HR_INICIO', T0.FIM 'HR_FIM', T0.TOTAL_HS 'TOTAL_HRS' 
    FROM dbo.TAPONTA_ABERTO T0
    UNION

    SELECT T0.OS 'OS', T0.COD_PROCESSO 'PP', T0.COD_TP_SERVICO 'TIPO_SERVICO', T0.COD_FUNCIONARIO 'FUNCIONARIO', T0.DATA 'DATA_INICIO', T0.DATA_FIM 'DATA_FIM', T0.INICIO 'HR_INICIO', T0.FIM 'HR_FIM', T0.TOTAL 'TOTAL_HRS' 
    FROM dbo.TAPS_AUX T0
    UNION

    SELECT T0.COD_OS_COMPLETO 'OS', T0.COD_BARR 'PP', T0.COD_TP_MAQUINA 'TIPO_SERVICO', T0.COD_FUNCIONARIO 'FUNCIONARIO', T0.DATA 'DATA_INICIO', T0.DATA_FIM 'DATA_FIM', T0.INICIO 'HR_INICIO', T0.FIM 'HR_FIM', T0.TOTAL_HS 'TOTAL_HRS' 
    FROM dbo.TCTRL_PH T0
)TEMP
ORDER BY TEMP.HR_INICIO ASC
```

Can you check this.